# Server 13.10, Raid1, LVM, EFI booting on 2nd disk

Tags: uefi, raid, lvm

I've read a whole bunch of posts of trying to get your Raid1 to boot up on the second disk if the first one failed. Nothing has failed yet, but I'm trying to test my setup. 2nd drive comes up with grub bash screen.

2 x WD red 3TB drives (mdadm raid1)

I have sda1 & sdb1 (/boot/efi) on their own partition and not in a raid1. I've read the /boot/efi can't be on raid1. Not sure if that's true or not, but for now they are on their each own partition. Maybe that could be my issue? I've read you can do it with /boot and but not with EFI. That's my main question, should I 'dd' the /boot/EFI partitions so they end up having the same UUID?

**/dev/sda**

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.7

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): A0F00B38-0030-4607-82E7-313822903BF0
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2925 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          249855   121.0 MiB   EF00  Ubuntu1
   2          249856      5860532223   2.7 TiB     FD00  raid1
```

**/dev/sdb**

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.7

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): A7E6C07D-839F-465D-B9CD-47E45CB62125
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2925 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          249855   121.0 MiB   EF00  Ubuntu2
   2          249856      5860532223   2.7 TiB     FD00  raid2
```

**blkid**

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="C70D-A319" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8a62e7a5-e67d-5620-346d-19327a22ac27" UUID_SUB="b1d472cf-cf30-2ddf-5dbf-0a709e179a90" LABEL="HomeServer:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="C70F-2DD1" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="8a62e7a5-e67d-5620-346d-19327a22ac27" UUID_SUB="269b71a5-2faf-3fd5-a33f-2975acae100a" LABEL="HomeServer:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md0: UUID="Pxo24d-8Phw-GW8b-kzWc-5CCs-I4Zq-Lp43hv" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap: UUID="ddccb365-e251-4ee1-a15c-b58295210885" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: LABEL="root" UUID="ebce6c83-50a7-448d-81cd-2a7a5585fa97" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-nas: LABEL="nas" UUID="c39a16f5-1644-4f6e-9005-1acf094220ca" TYPE="ext4"
```

I've done a fresh install of 13.10 sever and had to add grub2 to /dev/sdb1

```
 mount | grep sda1
 sudo umount /boot/efi
 sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi
 sudo grub-install --bootloader-id ubuntu2 /dev/sdb
 sudo umount /boot/efi
 sudo mount /boot/efi
```

That installed grub and added another option to my efi boot mgr. When looking at my /etc/fstab, it can only mount /boot/efi from sda1. If it fails over, how does fstab know to mount /boot/efi from sdb1 instead?

**/etc/fstab**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root      /               ext4    errors=remount-ro  0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=C70D-A319              /boot/efi       vfat    defaults            0       1

/dev/mapper/ubuntu-nas      /nas            ext4    defaults,acl        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap     none            swap    sw                  0       0
```

Edit:

---

I've DD sda1 to sdb1 and with the help of boot-repair, have 2 bootable grubs (among hours of trying stuff). Since I DD the partitions, the blkid UUID is the same. Here is my Boot Repair info. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7155022/

Still, when system tries to boot degraded, it just loops on 'Starting system degraded.' Have to use LiveCD and add the harddrive back to array before it can boot degraded.

Answer (score 0):

From your edit, I am guessing that the reason it loops when the system is degraded has to do with your grub.cfg. You have not shared that. Here is a sample (with indents to draw attention to insmod radi, search, bootdegraded) that I believe shows modifications you would need.

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-35-generic (raid)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
  insmod raid
  insmod mdraid1x
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 455cf8f6-532c-442c-814c-b8c4d280d170
  linux   /vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic root=UUID=455cf8f6-532c-442c-814c-b8c4d280d170 ro bootdegraded=true
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
}
```

Please post a follow-up.  I appreciate your follow-up edit, but I do not understand what changes you have implemented. Is your setup now working? Could you share your solution (including fstab) and current setup compared to the original?  You mentioned grub for sdb and modfications to the efi bootmanager. I am not following you on this. Do you have some code/commands you could share to elaborate?